# Ajv schema validation error when using `$merge`

Tags: node.js, ajv

When using `ajv` and `ajv-merge-patch` combined, data validation is  returning following error as well if there is one validation error.

```
should pass "$merge" keyword validation
```

as a validation error.
But when there is no validation error it returns empty.

```
const Ajv = require('ajv');
let ajv = new Ajv({ useDefaults: true, removeAdditional: true });
require('ajv-merge-patch')(ajv);

let schema = {
  $id: 'Job',
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    title: { type: 'string' },
  },
  additionalProperties: false,
};
ajv.addSchema(schema);

const createSchema = {
  $merge: {
    source: { $ref: 'Job' },
    with: {
      required: [
        'title',
      ],
    },
  },
};
const createValidator = ajv.compile(createSchema);

const data = {
  title: '',
};

if (!createValidator(data)) {
  console.log(createValidator.errors);
}
```

Comment: Your code works as expected; I don't see any issue here

Comment: @customcommander I checked it again and if I have an error it sends this error as well.
I'll update the question.